# Cursor on selected features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

I'm working on code, and I'm trying to select features by location. After the features are selected, I want the cursor will add "Yes" to "NearPoint3" field, only to the features that were selected.

Right now the word "Yes" is added to all features.

The relevant part is on the last section.

```
import arcpy
import os

input_folder = r'C:\Users\roniy\Documents\UN\arcpy_final\final_script\Early_childhood_frameworks.shp'
OutPut_Folder = r'C:\Users\roniy\Documents\UN\arcpy_final\final_script\out'
OutPut_intersect = r'C:\Users\roniy\Documents\UN\arcpy_final\final_script\out_inter'
out_copy = r'C:\Users\roniy\Documents\UN\arcpy_final\final_script\out_copy'
OutLayerSelection = r'C:\Users\roniy\Documents\UN\arcpy_final\final_script\sell_fin'
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
fc = "Early_childhood_frameworks"
os.path.join(OutPut_Folder, fc)
Buffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, OutPut_Folder, "100 Feet")
Intersect = arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Buffer, OutPut_intersect)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Buffer, "buffer")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Intersect, "intersect")
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("buffer", "INTERSECT", "intersect")
LayerSelection = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("buffer", out_copy)
clip = arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, LayerSelection, OutLayerSelection)

#------------------------------------------------------

NewField = arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "NearPoint3", "TEXT")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clip, "cliped_p")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "layer")
selection2 = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("layer", "INTERSECT", "cliped_p")
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["NearPoint3"])
for row in cursor:
    cursor.updateRow(["Yes"])
```

Comment: You shouldnt use `fc` as input to the UpdateCursor instead use the layer with the selection (i think its `"buffer"`)

Comment: This is a classic case of passing in a source to the cursor, instead of the layer.  The cursor requires a layer, and makes a new one (without the selection set) before using it. Pass the layer into the cursor.

Comment: right, it wored! thank you!!!

Comment: In this specific use case, there is no need to use an UpdateCursor to calculate the value of a single field in a selected set of records.  In fact, cursors can be quite slow for this kind of operation.  Instead, you should really just replace the UpdateCursor with [arcpy.CalculateField_management()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm).  All geoprocessing functions work on the currently selected set of features, accomplishing the task you described "in bulk" .